# Trying to display the 'country_of_manufacture' attribute on product view with extra html if value exists. Why does this code not work?

Tags: product, attributes, product-attribute, product-view

This is the php code I wrote for our product view page. It should only show on the front end if the variable has a value. yet the html still shows even if the product does not have the variable defined. Note: This is specific to the magento predefined country of manufacture attribute.

```
<?php 
    $coManufacturer = $this->getProduct()->getAttributeText('country_of_manufacture'); 
?>
<?php if ($coManufacturer): ?>
    <p><strong>Country of Origin:</strong> <?php echo $coManufacturer; ?></p>                           
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Which value do you get in a product with no value of that attribute? Dump the var to check it.

Comment: change your condition to `if (!empty($coManufacturer))` and then check again

Comment: @programmer_rkt I tried your suggestion and I get the same result.

Comment: @mbalparda I dumped the var and got this result: `string(1) " "`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the solution was to dump the var to understand what was being populated for the empty field of the attribute. Once I got that figured out, I was able to change the condition to this: `($coManufacturer!=" ")` which corrected the behavior. Thanks for your guys help!